# How can I demonstrate that a function space is not empty?

Tags: haskell, is-empty

I declared a class of types that admits a value:

```
class NonEmpty a where
    example :: a
```

And also, I declared the complement class:

```
import Data.Void

class Empty a where
    exampleless :: a -> Void
```

Demonstrating a function space is empty is easy:

```
instance (NonEmpty a, Empty b) => Empty (a -> b) where
    exampleless f = exampleless (f example)
```

But what about its complement? Haskell doesn't let me have these instances simultaneously:

```
instance Empty a => NonEmpty (a -> b) where
    example = absurd . exampleless

instance NonEmpty b => NonEmpty (a -> b) where
    example _ = example
```

Is there any way to bypass this problem?

Comment: So, this is a nitpick, but... `\_ -> ()` and `absurd`, the two implementations for `NonEmpty (Void -> ())`, are distinguishable functions in Haskell. Which behavior should it have? Any solution will have to choose one or the other, which seems unfortunate.

Comment: @DanielWagner I'm intrigued - in what concrete sense are `\_ -> () :: Void -> ()` and `absurd` distinguishable? They certainly agree on all possible input values (since there are 0 of them), which is as far as I understand it the "moral" definition of equality of functions. Presumably you mean there's some Haskell function/expression that will behave differently depending on which of these 2 functions you use - and if so I'd be intrigued to see one because I can't see myself how to construct one.

Comment: @RobinZigmond Morally equal, yep (hence calling it a nitpick). You have to be immoral to notice the difference: applying each to `undefined` will throw an exception in one case and give you `()` in the other, which you can distinguish in `IO`.

Comment: @DanielWagner thanks - I see, and I should have thought of that!

Comment: @DanielWagner I'm not a fan of these arguments, because if we're going to be pedantic nitpicks we could as well also point out that measuring runtime differences in `IO` would allow us to distinguish two copies of the exact same code compiled with different optimisation settings. IOW, _no_ laws / transformation rules could ever be formulated.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Okay, but these two implementations are actually different values in the domain (domain theory sense) of interest, right? Whereas an optimized version of a function is supposed to be the same value if the optimizer isn't buggy. That feels like a distinction worth making to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can merge the two classes together into one that expresses *decidability of whether or not the type is inhabited*:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, DataKinds
      , KindSignatures, TypeApplications, UndecidableInstances
      , ScopedTypeVariables, UnicodeSyntax #-}

import Data.Kind (Type)
import Data.Type.Bool
import Data.Void

data Inhabitedness :: Bool -> Type -> Type where
  IsEmpty :: (a -> Void) -> Inhabitedness 'False a
  IsInhabited :: a -> Inhabitedness 'True a

class KnownInhabitedness a where
  type IsInhabited a :: Bool
  inhabitedness :: Inhabitedness (IsInhabited a) a

instance ∀ a b . (KnownInhabitedness a, KnownInhabitedness b)
              => KnownInhabitedness (a -> b) where
  type IsInhabited (a -> b) = Not (IsInhabited a) || IsInhabited b
  inhabitedness = case (inhabitedness @a, inhabitedness @b) of
    (IsEmpty no_a, _) -> IsInhabited $ absurd . no_a
    (_, IsInhabited b) -> IsInhabited $ const b
    (IsInhabited a, IsEmpty no_b) -> IsEmpty $ \f -> no_b $ f a
```

To get again your simpler interface, use

```
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds #-}

type Empty a = (KnownInhabitedness a, IsInhabited a ~ 'False)
type NonEmpty a = (KnownInhabitedness a, IsInhabited a ~ 'True)

exampleless :: ∀ a . Empty a => a -> Void
exampleless = case inhabitedness @a of
   IsEmpty no_a -> no_a

example :: ∀ a . NonEmpty a => a
example = case inhabitedness @a of
   IsInhabited a -> a
```

Answer (score 5):

I don't think there's a really great way. The standard alternative is to use `newtype` wrappers to choose which instance the user wants in each case.

```
newtype EmptyDomain a b = ED { unED :: a -> b }
newtype InhabitedCodomain a b = IC { unIC :: a -> b }

instance Empty a => NonEmpty (EmptyDomain a b) where ...
instance NonEmpty b => NonEmpty (InhabitedCodomain a b) where ...
```